# Which TV does Sony recommend with PS4?

Tags: ps4

As Playstation 4 is Sony and Sony also make their own TVs. Is there a **Sony recommended** TV series that they recommend to use with the PS4?

Comment: For those voting to close as opinion. I am specifically asking for Sony recommendations, not for peoples opinions to avoid this exact thing.

Comment: To be fair, a recommendation is just that.  If you're using HDMI, it either works, or it doesn't.  There is no in between.

Comment: @Frank Looking at the answer, it seems there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the ***PlayStation 3D TV***

They advertise that this TV works well with the ***PlayStation*** consoles. This is done through the use of 3-1 display, which allows you to add three inputs to the TV, including the PS3. Secondly, it supports 3D, which is one of ***PlayStation's*** early advertising item,

But what is most important is **SimulView.** This eradicates split-screen gaming, by allowing two people to play on the same screen, but using it fully for both players. While how it does this will not be discussed here, here are the main points

- Stops the need to split the TV
- Gives full view for both playes
- Doesn't let you use 3D, but it never did anyway for splitscreen
- ONLY WORKS FOR 2-PLAYER

That's the only type of TV you are talking about. Link can be found:
[here](http://us.playstation.com/ps3/accessories/sony-playstation-3d-display-ps3/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

**No.**

Although Sony would clearly love for you to go out and buy a Bravia TV to go with your PS4, their PlayStation business avoids suggesting that one TV will work any better than another with the same basic technical capabilities.